# LibreOffice Writer: How to give a colored background to a table?

Tags: libreoffice

I want to color the background of a table (all its columns and rows) in a certain background color.

In Microsoft Word (which I basically no longer use) there's a bucket icon for that but I don't have one in LO Writer version 6.0.4.2, sadly.

How can this be done in LibreOffice Writer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select your column/line/case, you will see a little bar at bottom

You can see some icon, and select this one :
[image]

Answer (score 3):

- right click in the table
- select *Table properties...*
- click the *Background* tab
- select *For Table* from the dropdown menu

[image]